# Como cambiar un background-url en @media query

Tags: html, css, responsive

estoy haciendo un reto de front end mentor, y me dan imagenes para el responsive y para desktop, utilice las de desktop y ahora que estoy haciendo el responsive no se como cambiar la imagen, lo que hice primero claramente fue ir a el @media y linkear la imagen, pero no cambia nada, lo que tengo es esto:

HTML:

```
<section class="info"> // ----> Section que no utilice, lo tengo q borrar
<div class="info-grid">  // ----> Grid
  <div class="info-grid-one">  
    <h2>Transform your brand</h2>
    <p>We are a full-service creative agency specializing in helping brands grow ast.
      Engage your clients through compelling visuals that do most of the marketing for you. </p> // ----> texto
      <button>Learn more</button> // ----> Boton
    </div>
    <div class="info-img-first"></div> // ----> Imagen
    
    <div class="info-img-two"></div> // ---> Imagen
    <div class="info-grid-two">
      <h2>Stand out to the right audience</h2>
      <p>Using a collaborative formula of designers, researchers, photographers, videographers, and copywriters, we’ll
        build and extend your brand in digital places. </p> // ----> texto
        <button>Learn more</button> // ----> Boton
      </div>
</div>
```

Desktop:

```
section .info-img-first {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background-position: center;

background-image: url(./images/desktop/image-transform.jpg);
background-size: cover;
}
```

Responsive:

```
section .info-img-first {
background-image: url(./images/mobile/image-transform.jpg);
```

}

No se si tengo que anular de alguna forma la primer imagen en el responsive, intente varias cosas pero no funcionaron, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Saludos

Comment: Pudieras compartir el html también?

Comment: Claro, ahi lo edito

Comment: Listo @JeanGotopo,. agrege unos comentarios para que sea de un entendimiento mas rapido, tengo que mejorar mis estrucutras html y soy concienete :)

Comment: Ok estaré viendo tu problema para darte una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Debes procurar usar los media-queries para darle adaptabilidad o responsividad según dispositivo. Por otro lado, fíjate como he acomodado width y height para que pueda verse. Fíjate también que no es tan necesario agregar section en el css.

```css
 .info-img-first {
    width: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;

    background-image: url(./images/desktop/image-transform.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    }
   
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .info-img-first {
        
        background-size:cover;
        background-image:  url(./images/mobile/image-transform.jpg);
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="info"> 
        <div class="info-grid">
          <div class="info-grid-one">  
            <h2>Transform your brand</h2>
            <p>We are a full-service creative agency specializing in helping brands grow ast.
              Engage your clients through compelling visuals that do most of the marketing for you. </p> 
              <button>Learn more</button> 
            </div>
            <div class="info-img-first"></div> 
            
            <div class="info-img-two"></div> 
            <div class="info-grid-two">
              <h2>Stand out to the right audience</h2>
              <p>Using a collaborative formula of designers, researchers, photographers, videographers, and copywriters, we’ll
                build and extend your brand in digital places. </p>
                <button>Learn more</button> 
              </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```